# Is is possible to use NIO Selector for FileChannels in Java and/or Android?

Tags: java, android, selector, nio, channel

I am trying to read data from a file using NIO.  The thing is that the file is not just any file, but a file emulating a network device, i.e the tun0.  Various reasons mention the fact that the Selector cannot be used since the file is always present, but in this case its data is constantly changing and I need to receive that event immediately without having to poll.

So is there some way in which I can use the Selector, and if not, what are, if any, the similar high performance options?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FileChannel is not a SelectableChannel and therefore cannot be used with a Selector.

The 'various reasons' you quote aren't correct. You can use a file FD with select() in Unix.

Comment: I agree, it is not a SelectableChannel as I had a look at the sources, but I was searching for other ways in which I could have something similar. Essentially what your solution might mean is that I have a native select() and then call it from java, right?

Comment: That's not my 'solution'. That's my refutation of the 'various answers' you quoted that give an incorrect reason why you can't do this in Java. My solution would be to use blocking mode, java.io, and a dedicated thread.